# Drop table times out for non-empty tables; already adjusted timeout interval

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I'm having trouble deleting a table in MySQL v8.0 (on Windows 10) either from MySQL Workbench or via Python script (using mysql-connector-python). In both cases, the drop table command times out with "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

I previously set DBMS connection read timeout interval to 500 sec to try and work around this, but no luck.

The table in question has several hundred rows of data, and the entire .ibd file is 176kb. I suppose deleting the .ibd file directly isn't the greatest database practice?

I can create a new table and delete it, no problem. I'm running MySQL server locally.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: test **truncate table** and then **drop table**

Comment: Serveral hundreds of rows is not a large table. 176kb is tiny.

Comment: `DROP TABLE` should be very fast, regardless of the table size. I'm guessing that you have some other query holding a lock on that table.

Comment: @BerndBuffen, tried to truncate, but that put MySQL Workbench in 'Not Responding' state. Terminated the app in Win Task Mgr, relaunched app, tried truncate again, and again goes into 'Not Responding' state.

Comment: @jub it's probably a lock. do you have other queries running? have you tried to restart the mysql server itself?

Comment: Or look **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS** to see if there a lock

Comment: @obe, yes that would make sense. I use both MySQL Workbench and python to access this table, but everytime I access it in python, the last line executed is mydb.close() to close the connection. Is there a good test/check to see if there is a query that is locking the table?

Comment: @BerndBuffen result: 'InnoDB', '', '\n=====================================\n2021-05-07 12:04:44 0x72e8 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT\n=====================================\nPer second averages calculated from the last 19 seconds\n-----------------\nBACKGROUND THREAD\n-----------------\nsrv_master_thread loops: 97 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 201166 srv_idle\nsrv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0\n----------\nSEMAPHORES\n----------\nOS  It goes on and on, but too long to paste into comment.

Comment: @jub like Bernd suggested, you can use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. Unfortunately its output is not very intuitive, but there's plenty of information about it online. Other than that, you can reboot the mysql server, connect to it with MySQL Workbench without running the python or any other client - and try to `DROP TABLE`...

Comment: @obe, good call, I restarted the server, then was able to truncate and drop, and each took a fraction of a second. So it seems like that particular table got locked due to access from both Workbench and python. Database itself was not locked, since I could create/drop other tables. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@obe's suggestion to restart the server resolved the issue. So it seems like that particular table got locked due to access from both Workbench and python. Database itself was not locked, since I could create/drop other tables.